# Sum Left Outer Join In Subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working in a sub report. Visual Studio 2010 if relevant.

My first table has a unique record for every row in the details section.  I am then attempting to use a Left Outer Join to join a second table to the first but then sum those values where there may be more than one row in table two per table one.

Right now I am having a problem with row duplication and the values from table two will not sum and instead print out individually.  I have tried using groups and tried using Sum formula fields without success.

My first table is unique on a **Record Number**, **Component** and **Sequence**.
My second table also has those three items but may contain no record per the first table, one or multiple.

The **Record Number** and **Componen**t are passed to the report as parameters and are used in select expert.  So really **Sequence** is only a unique record in my first table.

I have tried Group By Record Number, Component and Sequence for Table one.  I have also tried Grouping by **Sequence** for Both Tables.  I have tried adding a sum formula and even tried a running total without success.

Is this something that is possible?  Is there something I may have missed trying?

Edit:

**What I am current getting**

```
Seq    T1 Data     T2 Data
10     A1          35
20     C2          25
20     C2          15
30     D5          30
40     D6          10
40     D6          50
```

**What I am looking for**

```
Seq   T1 Data    T2 Data
10    A1         35
20    C2         40
30    D5         30
40    D6         60
```

Comment: do you want to exclude duplicate value from being summed up?

Comment: if both of the tables got all 3 items (Record Number, Component and Sequence) then all 3 should be linked in subreport. That's why you are getting "strange" summaries.

Comment: @Siva no I do not want to exclude the data just sum multiple rows if they exist in Table 2 per Row in Table 1

Comment: @KuKeC I have all three of Record Number, Component and Sequence linked with a Left Outter Join in the subreport.  Record Number and Component are passed as Parameters to the subreport and are used in the Select Expert assigned to the respective DataBase columns of Table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  I grouped by Table 1 Sequence, then Table 2 Sequence (not sure if grouping by both is necessary).  Then I used a Running Total Field in Group Footer right after the details section (Group for Table 2) and set the Reset value to On change of group 1 (Table 1).